# Auto populate products in initial demands (stock.move table) in internal transfer (stock.picking) Error

Tags: python, odoo-10

All I want to do is from Location>in Current Stock Smart button (which is stock.quant table)
[image]

It allows selection of multiple records.
[image]

then I add action server button like post expense button.[image]

There is no problem with that and I already add or auto populate the product in initial demand (stock.move table) in internal transfer (stock.picking table)
[image]

but the problem is this when I click save it it tells that "The following fields are invalid: Stock Moves" but the stock moves is the the initial demand that I auto populate the data.
[image]

This is my code that auto populates the data in initial demand tab.

```
@api.onchange('stock_quant_ids')
def onchange_stock_quant_ids(self):
    print 'onchange_stock_quant_ids'

    stock_move_lines = []
    for stock_quant_rec in self.stock_quant_ids:
        print 'stock_quant_rec.product_id.name>', stock_quant_rec.product_id.name
        # stock_move_lines.append(stock_quant_rec.id)
        stock_move_lines.append({
            'picking_id': self.id,
            'name': stock_quant_rec.product_id.name,
            'product_id': stock_quant_rec.product_id.id,
            'product_uom_qty': stock_quant_rec.qty,
            'product_uom': stock_quant_rec.product_uom_id.id,
            'state': 'draft',
        })
    self.move_lines = stock_move_lines
```

and this is the code that will pop up the picking windows when you click post expense

```
@api.multi
def post_expense(self):

    stock_quant_ids = []
    stock_quant_holder = self.browse(self._context.get('active_ids'))
    for rec in stock_quant_holder:
        stock_quant_ids.append(rec.id)

    view_id = self.env.ref('stock.view_picking_form')

    return {
        'name': _('Transfer Expense'),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'stock.picking',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'target': 'new',
        'view_id': view_id.id,
        'views': [(view_id.id, 'form')],
        'context': {
            'default_stock_quant_ids': stock_quant_ids,
            'default_state': 'draft',
            # 'default_bool_loc': True,
            'default_picking_type_id': 5,
            'default_location_id': self.location_id.id,
            'default_location_dest_id': self.location_id.expense_location_id.id,
        }
    }
```

I Hope anyone can help me because I work this for almost a weeks. Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try ` self.move_lines = [6, 0, stock_move_lines]`

Comment: yes and its not working